# Finding white rectangle in an image

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to find a white rectangle in an image. The rectangle size is fixed. This is what I've come up as of yet:

```
BufferedImage bImage = bufferedImage;
int height = bufferedImage.getHeight(); //~1100px
int width = bufferedImage.getWidth(); //~1600px
int neededWidth = width / 2; 
int neededHeight = 150;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
boolean breaker = false;
boolean found = false;
int rgb = 0xFF00FF00;
int fx, fy;

fx = fy = 0;
JavaLogger.log.info("width, height: " + w + ", " + h);
while ((x != (width / 2) || y != (height - neededHeight)) && found == false) {
for (int i = y; i - y < neededHeight + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = x; j - x < neededWidth + 1; j++) { //Vareetu buut, ka +1 vajadziigs
        //JavaLogger.log.info("x,y: " + j + ", " + i);
        long pixel = bImage.getRGB(j, i);
        if (pixel != colorWhite && pixel != -1) {
            //bImage.setRGB(j, i, rgb);
            //JavaLogger.log.info("x,y: " + (j+x) + ", " + (i+y));
            breaker = true;
            break;

        } else {
            //bImage.setRGB(j, i, 0xFFFFFF00);
        }
        //printPixelARGB(pixel);
        if ((i - y == neededHeight-10) && j - x == neededWidth-10) {
            JavaLogger.log.info("width, height: " + x + ", " + y + "," + j + ", " + i);
            fx = j;
            fy = i;
            found = true;
            breaker = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (breaker) {
        breaker = false;
        break;
    }

}

if (x < (width / 2)) {
    x++;
} else {
    if (y < (height - neededHeight)) {
        y++;
        x = 0;
    } else {
        break;
    }
  }
//JavaLogger.log.info("width, height: " + x + ", " + y);
}

if (found == true) {

    for (int i = y; i < fy; i++) {
        for (int j = x; j < fx; j++) {
            bImage.setRGB(j, i, 0xFF00FF3F);
        }

    }

}
JavaLogger.log.info("width, height: " + w + ", " + h);
```

This works ok, if the rectangle I need is close to the begining of `(0;0)`, but as it get further away, the performance degrades quite severely. I'm wondering, if there's something that can be done?

For example, this search took nearly 8s, which is quite a lot. 
[image: One of searches]
I'm thinking, that this can deffinitely be done more effectively. Maybe some blob finding? Read about it, but I've no idea how to apply it.

Also, I'm new to both Java and Image processing, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  There was no need to post an image that is 1,191px × 1,684px!  Have you not heard of ***crop***?!?

Comment: This IS an SSCCE. Every part of the code is relevant to the problem. As to the image - yes there was. I put the whole image to display the scope of my problem. If the image was cropped, then it would seem, that getting to the bottom wouldn't take long. Now it's evident, that it would.

Comment: *"This IS an SSCCE."*  Say that as loud as you want, but it does not make it true. *"Every part of the code is relevant to the problem."*  Umm.. good.  What about the parts of the code needed to make it 'SC'?  In case you are confused, the issue with it is not the length of the code.  Did you actually *read* the link?  *"I put the whole image to display the scope of my problem."* One clever trick you can use to 'have your cake and eat it' (have a small image to download/use, as well as a large image to test with), is to embed a small image in the post then draw it to a large image at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very rough, but successfully finds all the white pixels in the image, more checking can be done to ensure it is the size you want and everything is there but the basics are there.

PS: I have not tested with your image. `r` and `this.rc` is picture size and `p` and `this.px` is the inner rectangle size

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final int r = 100;
    final int p = 10;

    NewJPanel pan = new NewJPanel(r, p, new A() {
        @Override
        public void doImage(BufferedImage i) {
            int o = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < i.getWidth() - p; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < i.getHeight() - p; k++) {

                    PixelGrabber pix2 = new PixelGrabber(
                            i, j, k, p, p, false);
                    try {
                        pix2.grabPixels();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

                    int pixelColor = pix2.getColorModel()
                            .getRGB(pix2.getPixels());

                    Color c = new Color(pixelColor);
                    if (c.equals(Color.WHITE)) {
                        System.out.println("Found at : x:" + j + ",y:" + k);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(pan);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private interface A {
    void doImage(BufferedImage i);
}

private static class NewJPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5348356640373105209L;

    private BufferedImage image = null;
    private int px;
    private int rc;
    private A a;

    public NewJPanel(int r, int p, A a) {
        this.px = p;
        this.rc = r;
        this.a = a;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    @Override public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        image = new BufferedImage(this.rc, this.rc,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, this.rc, this.rc);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(
                new Random().nextInt(this.rc - this.px),
                new Random().nextInt(this.rc - this.px),
                this.px, this.px);

        g.drawImage(image, this.rc, this.rc, this);
        this.a.doImage(this.image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I don't think the code is the problem - you need to change your algorithm. I would start by recursively searching for a single white pixel on the 2d plane, something like:

findWhitePixel(square){
   look at pixel in the middle of 'square' - if it's white return it, otherwise:
   findWhitePixel(top-right-quarter of 'square')
   findWhitePixel(top-left-quarter of 'square')
   findWhitePixel(bottom-right-quarter of 'square')
   findWhitePixel(bottom-left-quarter of 'square')
}

after you find a white pixel try travesing up, down, left and right from it to find the borders on you shape. if it's a given that there can only be rectangles - your done. if there might be other shapes (triangles, circles, etc.) you'll need some verification here.

Comment: How would your algorithm speed up the search process? As I see it, one would still need to go over nearly any pixel more than once.

Comment: Depending on the relative size of the white rectangle, you would only go over a handful of pixels before hitting a white one.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking can be solved by the operation known as "erosion". The erosion replaces every pixel by the darkest of all pixels in the rectangle of the requested size at that location (top-left corner). Here, darkest means that non-white supersedes white.

The output of erosion is an image with W-1 columns and H-1 rows less. Any white pixel in it corresponds to a solution.

In the lucky case of a rectangle shape, erosion is a separable operation. This means that you can erode first using an horizontal segment shape, then a vertical segment shape on the output of the first erosion. For a W x H restangle size, this replaces W * H operations by W + H, a significant saving.

In the also lucky case of a binary image (non-white or white), erosion by a segment can be done extremely efficiently: in every row independently, find all contiguous runs of white pixels, and turn the W-1 rightmost ones to non-white. Do the same to all columns, shortening the white runs by H-1 pixels.

Example: find all 3x2 rectangles:

```
####....####
##.....#..##
#..######...
.....###....
```

After 3x1 erosion:

```
####..####
##...#####
#########.
...#####..
```

After 1x2 erosion:

```
####.#####
##########
#########.
```

This algorithms takes constant time per pixel (regardless the rectangle size). Properly implemented, should take a handful of milliseconds.